# "updating from wolfram research server"

Tags: import, web-access

I failed to get the information on a website after several attempts, every time Wolfram Mathematica returned "updating from wolfram research server". Could anyone give me any advise? Thanks a lot!!!

Here it is my code:

```
googl1 = Import["http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/history/fi-126.1.GOOGL.NAS", 
 "XMLObject"];
```

Comment: Could it be something wrong with your internet connection? When I copy/paste the above command, the variable googl1 contains a reasonablly sized item starting with `XMLObject["Document"]`

Comment: [Did you try restarting Mathematica?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! @bills: I think it returned exactly what I needed on your computer. But I don't think there are anything wrong with my internet connection, because I can refer to to the "Wolfram Language Documentation Center" easily.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I've restarted the kernel for many times, but it still failed...

Comment: I meant restart the whole system (including the front end), not just the kernel. Then after the kernel has started up, wait for a few seconds before you evaluate anything.

Comment: @Szabolcs Do you mean "First close both the files and the exe, then start it again"? Still failed... Sobbing.

Comment: I mean use to File -> Exit (or Quit).  You might try deleting your `$UserBaseDirectory/Paclets` directory (after having made a backup!) ... This will remove any example data that was downloaded, as well as any third party packages that use the paclet system.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you so much!!! Succeeded at last! I can finally continue doing my homework!

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm sorry to disturb, but when I used the method you've told me for the second time, I still failed, do you have any suggestions?